# Can't start laravel php server on Mac OS

Tags: php, laravel

i want to start developing with laravel on my Mac OS machine, I installed XAMPP, brew installed php and cloned my laravel repository into my Mac OS.

However when I use php artisan serve I get the following:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18

Warning: require(/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/wooloveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.6/share/php/pear') in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.6/share/php/pear') in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/wooloveapp.com/artisan on line 18
gabriel@MacBook-Pro-de-Gabriel wooloveapp.com % sudo php artisan serve
Password:
PHP Warning:  require(/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18

Warning: require(/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/wooloveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.6/share/php/pear') in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.2.6/share/php/pear') in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/loveapp.com/artisan on line 18
```

Comment: Did you run `composer install`?

Comment: you should run `composer install` first at all,
second `php artisan migrate` and `php artisan key:generate`